# Laravel Model Class

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a database called User with millions of data.
Is it possible to limit the data access in the model class file, let say the latest 500?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    // limit data here, equivalent to User::latest()->take(500);
}
```

So that when I access the model in controller I will only get the latest 500 data?

```
$data = User::all();  // only get the latest 500
```

Comment: read here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset

Comment: As `$data = User:limit(50)->get();`

Comment: also check pagination https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Comment: @JohnLobo But this is executed in the controller. I'm looking for a way to manipulate the data from the Model class, not the controller.

Comment: Query scopes might help you. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: @SimonK It achieves my purpose but I still need to use User::nameOfScope->get() . Is there any way to make  User::all() work?

Comment: @SimonK global scope will make it work! Thanks